# android kotlin property does not change with passed method to adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter

i have defined a val in my fragment like so

```
 private var selectionMode: Boolean = false
```

and a property to change it

```
fun enableSelectionMode() {
        selectionMode = true
    }
```

and i passed both to Adapter and want to call `enableSelectionMode` after clicking on each recycler item but nothing happen

here is my fragment:

```
    class PostsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val model: PostsViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private var selectionMode: Boolean = false

    fun enableSelectionMode() {
        selectionMode = true
    }

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_posts, container, false)

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.posts_recycler)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context)

        model.posts.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { items ->
            recyclerView.adapter = PostsAdapter(items, model, selectionMode,
                ::enableSelectionMode)
        })

        return view
    }

}
```

and my adapter

```
        class PostsAdapter(
    private val posts: List<Post>,
    private val model: PostsViewModel,
    private val selectionMode: Boolean,
    private val enableIt: () -> Unit
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        private const val TYPE_FROM = 0
        private const val TYPE_TO = 1
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var postContent: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content)
        var selectPostCheckBox: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_select_checkbox)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {


        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(
                if (viewType == TYPE_TO) R.layout.to_post else R.layout.from_post,
                parent,
                false
            )

        return ViewHolder(view)

    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.selectPostCheckBox.visibility = if (selectionMode) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        holder.postContent.text = selectionMode.toString()
        holder.selectPostCheckBox.setImageResource(R.drawable.cursor_color)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener() {
            enableIt()
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = posts.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

        return posts[position].selfPost
    }
}
```

Comment: You're never notifying the adapter of your changes, it can't automatically watch for property changes. You're also using `selectionMode` when the view holder gets created, whereas it should be used when binding.

Comment: Can you please help me where should i change ? I am stuck to this for a week

Comment: Have you implemented my suggestions?

Comment: @HenryTwist i moved `selectionMode` from holder created to holder binding, and put `notifyDataSetChanged()` on click listener still same result

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question with the new code so we can see what you're doing wrong?

Comment: @HenryTwist updated, when i set `selectionMode` to true a checkbox should appear next to all items its not about a specific item

Comment: Okay so the problem how is that you're never changing `selectionMode` in your adapter. When you click, `enableIt()` is called which calls `enableSelectionMode` in your fragment, which changes the `selectionMode` variable *in your fragment*, not in the adapter.

Comment: @HenryTwist yeah that's it , i call `notifyDataSetChanged` but it does not work, when i call `enableIt()` and navigate to next fragment and then back `selectionMode` is true and all items show the checkbox so yes the problem is notify adapter and really dont know how to do that

Comment: You haven't mentioned a navigation problem in your question, does the checkbox show/hide after you click the row now?

Comment: its not related to navigation, just wanted to inform you `enableIt()` works and we just need to notify adapter

Comment: Ah I see, well like I've said, I don't think it does do what you're expecting. The reason it works when navigating is because you recreate your adapter. You need to change `selectionMode` *in your adapter* when the row is clicked.

Comment: @HenryTwist exactly! and the question is how we can update the adapter?

Comment: You can call `selectionMode = true`?

Comment: @HenryTwist it working now well , even without calling `enableIt()` , I guess there is no need to pass class method to change the property in some situation like so , just need to define a property in Fragment, isn't it?

Comment: Well you might want to persist the state for rotation etc, so it probably would be useful for the fragment to be aware of the change, however it's not necessary if you have no purpose for it.